# AlertDialog bits of the text missing and not following the weight distribution

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-layout-weight

I'm having problems with my custom AlertDialog.
As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6WhM.png), bits of the Positive/Negative Button text are missing and the views overlap each other while i use weight-mechanisme. I'm testing on the emulator: Nexus 5x Google API's level 22. I have two questions:

1. How can fix the missing bits in text?
2. How can let the views not overlap each other?

This is my custom AlertDialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog_team_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog_snapshot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog_info_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:hint="@string/sighting_input_dialog_hint">
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here i build the AlertDialog, the buffer implements the OnClickListener interface.

```
/**
 * Sets the Context for the Dialog of the SightingSession.
 * */
public Builder setDialogContext(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sighting_input_dialog, null);
    buffer.dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Bevestigen", buffer)
            .setNegativeButton("Annuleren", buffer)
            .setView(view)
            .create();

    return this;
}
```

In this code, i show and use the dialog. The first OnClick method is for the AlertDialog, the second is for a Snackbar. In the onSnapshotReady() method i set the drawable of the ImageView.

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
    switch (i)
    {
        case AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            if(callback != null) {
                callback.onSightingCompleted(lastLatLng, deelgebied, ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.sighting_dialog_info_edit)).getText().toString());
                destroy();
            }
            break;
        case AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            snackbar.show();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(deelgebied != null) {
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lastLatLng, 12), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if(dialog != null) {
                    dialog.show();
                    ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.sighting_dialog_title)).setText("Bevestig de " + type);
                    ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.sighting_dialog_team_label)).setText("Deelgebied: " + deelgebied.getName());
                }
                googleMap.snapshot(SightingSession.this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        });

    } else {
        snackbar.setText("Selecteer een geldige locatie!");
        snackbar.show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(dialog != null) {
        ((ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.sighting_dialog_snapshot)).setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Japp.getAppResources(), bitmap));
    }
}
```

As requested by Pztar here is the styles.xml file.

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShowCaseTheme" parent="ShowcaseView">
        <item name="sv_backgroundColor">#e51249d9</item>
        <item name="sv_showcaseColor">#9966ff</item>
        <item name="sv_buttonText">Oke</item>
        <item name="sv_titleTextAppearance">@style/ShowCaseTitle</item>
        <item name="sv_detailTextAppearance">@style/ShowCaseDetail</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShowCaseTitle" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShowCaseDetail" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title.Light">
        <item name="android:textColor">#deffffff</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"></style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Try supplying a `theme` in your `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor eg. `new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog_Alert)`

Comment: @Pztar I created a custom theme with as parent `AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light`, and set the AlertDialog's theme. This seems to resolve bits missing and the overlapping views, but now the AlertDialog takes up the whole screen. I can't click on the Positive/Negative button, can i make the AlertDialog the normal size again?

Comment: Make sure you're extending from `Alert` not the general parent theme.

Comment: I can't edit my comment but your `style` would look like this, `<style name="MyCustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">`

Comment: @Pztar I use this style now `<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"></style>` Now the dialog is no longer fullscreen, but the other two problems come back

Comment: Yes, for your `Dialog` only use the theme: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` if you use just `Theme.AppCompat.Light` it will treat your dialog as a full screen rather than a dialog.

Comment: Can you post your `theme` xml file? The last thing I can suggest is to try using a `ContextThemeWrapper` instead of just plain `context` which would become `AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.MyCustomDialog));`

Comment: @Pztar I have included the styles.xml in the bottom of the post, the ContextThemeWrapper results in the dialog showing up in normal size and the button text displayed well. But the weight still doesn't work, [here](http://imgur.com/a/PN2AO) you can see the new situation

Comment: From here, it just looks like a spacing issue now. Try giving your `TextViews` some margin room or padding

Comment: @Pztar I changed the padding and the views still overlap each other the same amount. I have changed my layout to a ScrollView and that works for me. I don't see the use in figuring out this problem if i can resolve it by using something else. I hope this doesn't irritate you. Anyways many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my custom dialog layout, now the top level view is a ScrollView. This works around my problem, but isn't the solution. This is the new layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog_team_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog_snapshot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sighting_dialog_info_edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/sighting_input_dialog_hint">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```